# Parabolic Reflections

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I'm given an equation $g(x)=-\frac{1}{2} x^2 -3$

It's easy for me to find the vertex of $(0,-3)$.  I see this has a vertical compression of $0.5$.  It's not easy for me to see the line about which it is reflected.  I would think it is reflected about the line $y=-3$, but the book says about the line $y=1.5$.  Must be a typo or am I not understanding the reflections?

Comment: By reflected, are you talking about about the line of symmetry of the parabola?

Comment: By any chance, did your book say $y=-1.5$ instead of $y=1.5$?

Comment: Definitely NOT talking about line of symmetry.  Isn't the answer reflected about y=-3?

Comment: Reflected... as in what?  It is clear we don't know what you mean by 'relfected'.  Could you provide a definition/example?

Comment: I think the "reflection" refers to the parabola's directrix.